# Unable to run Android Emulator using WHPX on Azure VM

Tags: android, azure, android-emulator, hyper-v

I following the guide here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin

to run Android Emulator using Windows Hypervisor Technology. I'm currently working on Azure VM D_v3 series. During debug my sample app, I've got this error:

```
2>emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
2>emulator: CPU Acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator. Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.
2>emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
2>Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
2>CPU acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator. Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.
```

WHPX is for sure enabled in Windows Features. Have any idea? Is it possible with azure?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling OpenGL. It worked for me in a DSv3 VM.

It can be disabled by going to Program Files (or Program Files x86 if you're on a 64-bit machine)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\SKUs\Android\xdesku.xml and deleting this line: GuestDisplayProvider="VsEmulator.OpenGLGuestDisplay".

If there are multiple versions under xde, pls identify which version has SKUs\Android.

Ref:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7c0bbc5-eb29-4080-8398-e55111d98c91/vs-android-emulator-cannot-boot?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 0):

Today's version of Azure VM may not have full nested virtualization capabilities enabled which may not allow Android emulator on Azure. Dsv3 or Esv3 version machines only have nested virtualization enabled. I tried and could not run Android emulator. While for now you can use Visual Studio Emulator for Android [older version of Android API]on Azure VM. Refer details for step by step guide - https://www.sanganakauthority.com/2020/04/run-android-emulator-and-android-studio.html